# moving img from left to right , stop for 5 seconds with change the img then continue moving to right with the old img agin vanilla js

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I have two images of walking cat and dancing cat

I need to move the walking cat img till the middle of the window then change img to dancing cat and still pause for 5 seconds dancing, after 5 seconds the walking cat returns again and  continue walking till the end of the window and then starts again from the beginning of the window

I use setTimeout , setInterval and clearInterval for the pause
so the cat walking till the middle then paused and danced , after 5 seconds return walking but not moving till the end of the window

is there a way to return interval after clearing in this code ? Thanks

```js
let img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
img.style.left = 0
let x = 0

function moving() {

  if(x ===  ((window.innerWidth)-400)/2 ) {
    img.setAttribute('src' , 'dancing cat src')
    setTimeout(() => {
      img.setAttribute('src' , 'walkingCat src')
    }, 5000)
    clearInterval(interval)

  } else {
    x >= (window.innerWidth)-300 ?  x = 0 : x += 10
    img.style.left = x +'px'

  }  


}
const interval =  setInterval(moving , 50)
```

```html
<img>
```

Comment: If you click `[<>]` and then go to loremkitten, you can provide a [mcve]

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: leftStart is no defined`. _"s there a way to return interval after clearing in this code"_ No, but you can start a new interval in the `setTimeout` callback function => `setTimeout(() => { img.setAttribute('src' , 'walkingCat src'); interval =  setInterval(moving , 50); }, 5000)`

Comment: thank you ,, it works
 but set a varible before the function first , 

in if condition  -> clearInterval
in setTimeout  -> setInterval to the varible